# When using jasypt, how do I get the encrypted value to put in my config?

Tags: spring-boot, encryption, jasypt

I have a Spring Boot project where I need to encrypt some properties in application.properties. I've tried using jasypt, but I quickly ran into a problem: How do I encrypt the property to put in the config? I found some webpages that would let me encrypt and decrypt, but they used the old algorithm instead of the new default PBEWITHHMACSHA512ANDAES_256.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the mvn command to get the encrypted value to your config file.

For example, if you want to encrypt the value *mySecret* place the value as a property in the application.properties file enclosed within brackets and prefixed by DEC.

```
secret.property.example.value=DEC(mySecret)
```

Now run the encrypt command with mvn by specifying the password.

```
mvn jasypt:encrypt -Djasypt.encryptor.password="myPassword"
```

Running the above command will generate the encrypted secret value and store it in the properties file. Your value would look something like this

```
secret.property.example.value=ENC(mySecretEncrypted)
```

You can directly read the value in the application with @Value annotation and the string you get there will already be decrypted.